# Is there a real fix for El Capitan sound issues?

Tags: macos, audio, mac-pro

On a 2010 Mac Pro, using a new drive, doing a fresh install, I have no sound, not even a startup chime (when the El Cap drive is set as the startup drive in the control panel).  From the numerous articles I've found, I tried the usual fixes, after doing all of the available updates.

Checklist of attempts to fix:

1. reset the SMC
2. reset the NVRAM
3. checked the headphone jack (reports of debris, etc.)
4. checked the Sound control panel (all devices list properly, and recognizes presence/absence of headphones)
5. tried switching between devices
6. tried `sudo kill coreaudio`
7. deleted the `com.apple.audio...` pref and restarted

None of these had any effect.

Also, it's highly unlikely to be the hardware.  The new drive (with El Capitan), is a second drive.  The first drive is running 10.6.8, and has no sound issues when I boot up from it.  It's only happening when booting into El Capitan.

Any other suggestions that I've overlooked?

Aside:  I had the same happen with a MacBook Pro, and El Cap.  I spent a day on that as well, but whatever fixed that, isn't fixing on this.  There's the oddity that one account works normally, but the other account gives no screen feedback, or sound feedback, that the volume is changing, but the volume does work, and does change.

Comment: Can you see the device in the hardware report?  (About this Mac -> System Report)

Comment: I'll have to check that, but as I mentioned, it does show up in the Sound control panel.  I see "Internal Speaker", and if I plug something into the jack, it switches to say "Headphones".  Are you thinking a driver issue?

Comment: On the MacBook, I don't know the default, but on the account that was upgraded to El Cap, under the Sound Effects tab, I discovered that the "Play feedback when volume is changed" box, was unchecked, so I hear a sound change now, but no on-screen volume indicator.  Still hasn't fixed the Mac Pro.